# Ошибка при запуске приложения без отладки C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, visual-studio

При запуске приложения без отладки появляется ошибка.
[image: Ошибка]

При этом, если запустить приложение из Visual Studio с отладкой, то ошибка не возникает. Насколько я понимаю, ошибка возникает при подключении к БД.

```
string CommandText = "";
string Connect = "Database='test' ;Data Source='****' ;User Id='****' ;Password='****' ;charset='utf8'";
MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(Connect);
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(CommandText, myConnection);
try
{
    myConnection.Open();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при подключении к БД" + " " + e.Message);
}
```

Comment: "При запуске приложения без отладки появляется ошибка" - release не запускается или не работает вне среды студии?

Comment: Release запускается. Я запускал приложение из под папки Debug, выдавало ошибку. Спасибо.

Comment: Если проблема решилась, то видимо стоит написать об этом в ответе и "принять" его, чтобы вопрос перешел в разряд решенных и не отвлекал посетителей форума.

Comment: Я не знаю как можно принять комментарий в качестве ответа, а свой ответ я не смогу ещё 2 дня принять, так что, может, вы оформите ответ, а я отмечу его как верный? @АлександрМуксимов

Comment: Проблема :). Какой-то очень куцый ответ получается, ну попробуем.

Comment: `" + " " +` зачем?

Comment: @tCode Это просто пробел. Чтобы не выглядело следующим образом: "...к БДИнициализация типа..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы запускаете приложение на С# или managed c++ из папки debug, требующее коннекта к базе данных, которое благополучно работало в среде студии при отладке, но без студии получаете Exception при подключении  к базе данных, то попробуйте сделать то же самое с версией release, убедившись что автоматически сгенерированные config файлы не содержит лишних connection strings.